# Switch Audio Track for Chromecast, when using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, chromecast, exoplayer2.x

I am making a streaming app with cast functionality and I'm facing issues regarding the sync between the exoplayer controls and the cast session.

I need to sync the selected audio track for an ExoPlayer instance in my android App and the current chromecast session, which is already working fine.

Now I know, that you can set an active track Id, using the CastContext from the exoplayer lib, but I dont know where to get the required id from. I cant find any way of getting it from the exoplayer instance, but I also dont have it stored as a field somewhere in my code, since the exoplayer fetches those URIs itself.

Apart from the docs, I've been searching through, I have found some information about querying the available tracks of the exoplayer instance here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer/track-selection. But it only shows how to get a limited number of attributes for specific tracks. I could not find any way of getting the track itself or any id or uri for it.

Any help is highly appreciated, since I have the feeling it is such a simple problem, yet I just cant seem to find the solution. Nobody seems to talk about it either...

I've read through multiple docs to find any hint of how to achieve something useful, but to no avail.

If I remember correctly, there is an Activity one could use, which automatically handles events and controls like this, but that is not an option here unfortunately, since the whole thing is wrapped inside of a flutter app... So we gotta work with a PlatformView.

I have also asked ChatGPT, but he insists, that there is a MediaTrack object for every track, which I cant seem to find in the docs.

I would honestly expect something really easy to return some kind of track object, which provides an id, uri and everything regarding the sources and metadata.